# Web GUI Merge Requests Failing after Gitlab Update to 6.6.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, merge, ubuntu-12.04, gitlab

I ran the updates from 5.4 to 6.6.4 to our system and now merge requests in the web gui do not work.  All the checks in gitlab pass and the application is configured correctly - all green lights in the checks.

At first we were getting the endlessly spinning "Checking for ability to automatically merge…" status.  Clearing the gitlab-satellites folder resolved that issue.

Now, we get the box to "accept merge request"  and it appears that the merge goes through but, it does not.

Any ideas on what is going on and how to fix it?

Thanks

#### System information

System:     Ubuntu 12.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p247
Gem Version:    2.0.3
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.1.1

Comment: Errors from log file

March 05, 2014 11:05 -> ERROR -> Command failed [1]: /usr/bin/git --git-dir=/Data/repos/git/gitlab-satellites/test/testproject/.git push origin tmp

remote: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.1.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)